# Editable Sitecore text field within a Sitecore Glass link field renderer

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

Using standard sitecore controls (Link and Text), you can embed a text field within a link in the following way:

```
<sc:Link runat="server" Field="LinkUrl" >
        <sc:Text runat="server" Field="LinkText" />
</sc:Link>
```

That will give you the ability to edit the text of one field and link of another field.

I have tried to replicate this using Glass, but have been unsuccessful. Something like this would be good (It doesn't work):

```
<%= Editable( x => x.LinkUrl,new { Text = Editable(Model,q => q.LinkText,null)}) %>
```

Is there another way of sorting this out?

There are *two* options I see if I cannot do this using standard glass functionality:

1. Change the GlassHtml code
2. Use Two Fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Razor use this:

```
@using (BeginRenderLink(x => x.Link, isEditable: true))
{
    @Editable(x => x.Title);
}
```

If you are using WebForms:

```
<%using(BeginRenderLink(x=>x.Link){ %>

    <%=Editable(x=>x.Title) %>

<% } %>
```

Mike

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Glass version 3, then you can't use `Editable` on `Link` and `Image` fields.
Use `RenderLink` and `RenderImage` instead.

See here: http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial22/tutorial22.html

> The Editable method is the most basic method to use to make a field
>   editable and should be used with most fields that are page editable
>   except the Image field and General Link field

Comment: Ruud this has changed in you can now push Links and IMages through the Editable method.